# How can I insert data without specifying a value for a non auto-increment primary key?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)


1. insert into persons values (1, 'John', 'Smith', 'LA', 'LA');
2. insert into persons (p_id, lastname, firstname, address, city) values  (2, 'John', 'Smith', 'LV', 'LV');
```

How can I insert data into a table, without specifying a value for a primary key (the primary key doesn't have the "auto_increment" attribute).

I tried with:

> 1. insert into persons values ('John', 'Smith', 'LA', 'LA');
> 2. insert into persons values (null, 'John', 'Smith', 'LA', 'LA');
> 3. insert into persons values (auto, 'John', 'Smith', 'LA', 'LA');

but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this implemented as

- DEFAULT value on the PK column (say -9999)
- A table that holds the Current_PK value
- An INSERT trigger that changes that PK from -9999 to Current_PK and increments Current_PK

Another way that I have seen is to get the MAX from the table and increment it and put it into the new row.

I must say, that both these methods caused bad data, caused locking and blocking and degraded performance.

In your case, I do not see a way other than actually specifying a value for PK.

Comment: At a place where I worked, we had a table of these primary keys ( tablename, nextkey ) tuples. One day somebody did an UPDATE intending to update one key's value but run the query forgetting the WHERE clause. Suffice to say it took several hours to get things straightened out!

Answer (score 6):

Primary keys cannot be null, and if you don't set them to auto increment, then how does MySQL know what you want to put in the table?  You need to either specify the ID (perhaps by selecting the MAX(P_Id) and adding 1 to it) or set it to auto increment.

Although simply adding an auto increment field is definitely the best approach, you could try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (P_Id, FirstName, LastName, Address, City)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(P_Id) + 1 FROM Persons), 'John', 'Smith', 'LA', 'LA');
```

This uses a subselect, so if you're using an old version of MySQL it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select p_id+1 From Person OrderBy p_id desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

When loading a row into a table with auto-increment you can specify a value provided that value is NOT less than the highest value in that key. This works the same as a UNIQUE key and will error as if it is a duplicate. Otherwise it will treat the new loaded value as the new highest value for that key.

I am most curious to know why anyone would want to use a primary key without using auto-increment. The auto-increment makes for a most elegant way of avoiding duplicate data in any table. If the rest of the data is identical with another row in that table it can be identified and fixed/deleted. Used in combination with another row which is a unique key (to catch any duplicates) the table becomes very robust.

ianm